# How is energy transferred between atoms in a collision?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, atoms

Consider two bare protons.  One (A) is stationary (relative to some arbitrary massless observer); the other (B) is approaching A at 1 m/s.  When they collide, I assume that they bounce.

What is the precise mechanism by which energy is transferred from A to B?

For bonus points: Is the mechanism the same if each proton has one electron (that is, a normal hydrogen atom)?

Comment: I don't know if relevant to this particular scattering, but a normal hydrogen atom has one neutron too ;)

Comment: @Nivalth: The normal deuterium atom has one neutron, but the normal hydrogen atom doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for the whole theory of scattering developed the past 80 years.

Please have a look at this lecture which covers [proton proton scattering.](http://folk.uio.no/finnr/talks/pp-scattering.pdf)

In a nutshell, any scattering transfers momentum and energy between target and incoming with the exchange of a [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) gauge boson and possibly other  allowed by quantum numbers particles. A virtual particle exchange.

A scattering of hydrogen on hydrogen involves only the electromagnetic exchanges, i.e. virtual photons.